# jquery: hover button for controlling a div's scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, scroll

i'm having a div with lots of content and a vertical scrollbar. i'd like to replace the scrollbar with an up/down button in order to scroll the content on hovering the buttons.
any ideas how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
var timeoutId = 0;

function scrollIt(amount){
    $('div').scrollTop($('div').scrollTop()+amount);
}

$('.down').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(scrollIt(5), 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

$('.up').mousedown(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(scrollIt(-5), 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin might be helpful: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Answer (score 1):

I think based on this, you'll get a pretty good start on how to do this.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12